# How to move the search button inside the search bar?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I'm building a Rails app. How can I build a search bar that contains the search button inside it? An example would be the Stackoverflow search bar at the top of the page. Here's my search bar so far:

```
<div id= "searchbar">
  <%= form_tag things_path, :method => :get do %>
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
      <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="thing-search">Go</i></button>
      <%#<div="Go"><%= submit_tag "Go", :name => nil </div> %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: The SO search bar doesn't actually have a button. Just a background image

Comment: The way Stack Overflow places the magnifying glass is just by using an SVG background image and an `input[type="text"]`.

Comment: Another way could be to style the text input plain (without border, effects etc), style the button as you want and set searchbar-like styles for the wrapper arround the text input and search button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a loot at Bootstrap [Button Groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons). They're essentially exactly what you're looking for and rolling bootstrap into a rails app is fairly simple. At the very least it will give you a good design to work off of.